# Relative url in form action doesn't interpret php, full url does. Why?

Tags: php, forms, action

I have installed a LAMP server (Ubuntu 20.4; PHP 7.4.3).
If I make a form and set action with an absolute URL (http://localhost/try.php) there is no problem but if i use relative url (try.php) the browser (firefox) tells me if i want to open php file.
Is the problem in the browser or php settings?

Sorry for my English

Example: I have a 'index.html' file in localhost (I open it from Nautilus with firefox), in this files there is a form.
This works fine:

```
<form action="http://localhost/grabar.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This works wrong (firefox asks me how to open grabar.php file):

```
<form action="grabar.php" method="post">
   <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Another discovery: they both work fine, if I open the file from firefox by entering in the navigation bar: 'localhost/index.html'. If I open it from another program (Nautilus, Bluefish), firefox opens 'file: //var/www/html/index.html' and gives me the above problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please show an example of each.

Comment: what about chrome?

Comment: try `action="/grabar.php"` instead if `action="grabar.php"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is only the syntax of your `<form action="/script.php" method="post"...>` then yes use absolute URLS like I do here.

If you are trying to open the file locally with an editor, firefox try to open that file as notepad could try to if you ask to do so.

The point is Firefox could resolve hostnames and can display html ouput from files (interpreted as php can produced, or not interpreted as static or raw html) from their hostnames (with http(s):// protocol) or from their files (with files:// protocol).

Firefox is not able to interpret your php file directly so it sends you directly that file and tell you to go further yourself. It is not his perimeter. It is not able to do that. A php interpreter is working on inside your apache webserver, so it can do that, and that is the difference.